# Ubuntu Huge Memory Use

Tags: 17.04, ram, memory-usage, web-development

I'm having some issue with Ubuntu. I am learning web developing and decided to use Ubuntu as my OS (on a different drive I have W10). I tried both Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Ubuntu 17.04 (although I just got an update).

My problem is that running 3 tabs in Chrome, 2 terminals doing nothing and VSCode running a create-react-app development server would do this:

[image: slow-screenshot]

Slowing down my computer to the point that I can't do anything. (I believe that 4GB of RAM is more than enough for what I need)

On W10 I can run a lot of more applications and Chrome Tabs without any issue but with Ubuntu for some reason I can't.

My PC specs:

[image: specs]

As of writing this, this is what System Monitor shows me:

[image: system-monitor]

Maybe one of this "Additional Drivers" is causing this issue(?):

[image: drivers?]

I hope someone has an idea of why this is going on, because I really want to use Ubuntu.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like your preferred setup needs about 1.5-2 more gig of RAM to prevent swapping. Use the `top` command to see which applications are using your memory. If you discover a memory leak, please file a bug report. If you believe that a specific app is using too much memory, feel free to contact the app's development team and explain.

Comment: What's the output of `free -m`?

Comment: So what seems to help is upgrading to 17.10 and using Firefox instead of Chrome. Huge improvement. Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one or more applications have a memory leak. This bug may have been fixed already. Try

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Something that I encountered with using Ubuntu is that when I killed Firefox from htop, it kept the tabs that were open in RAM (not cache), so that "free" would show about 2.8G RAM usage. When I reopened Firefox the two tabs opened right back up and I was surprised that they stayed around. Once I closed down Firefox properly, the RAM was freed and I was back down to my usual 1.8G.

(Adding as an answer since I can't comment)